# Use nx app generators/plugins in package-based monorepos?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nx-devkit

Is it possible to use nx code generators/plugins, i.e. `@nrwl/react:application my-app` in a package-based monorepo?
The docs (https://nx.dev/concepts/integrated-vs-package-based) say following:

> At the most basic level, package-based repos utilize Nx's core features while integrated repos also use the plugin features

Does that mean that plugins can only be used when integrated approach is used?